# Convert NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut to Int

Tags: swift

Try to find a way to convert plain English number (e.g., One, Two...) to Int (e.g., 1, 2...)

I know that there is way to convert from Int to English using

```
numberFormatter:NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut
var string = numberFormatter.string(from: 3) // "three"
```

Is there any reverse way of converting this?

I am trying to avoid using array of String like `["One", "Two"..]`

Answer (score 3):

Number formatters work in both directions, so you can just use:

```
let num = numberFormatter.number(from: string)
```

But you'll need to take some care to make sure it exactly matches the output of the forward direction. `"three"` will translate to 3, but `"Three"` won't.

As Sulthan notes, this is absolutely sensitive to the locale of the formatter (which you can set to be different than the user's locale if that's necessary). It is strongly assuming that the input and output from the same formatter match.

Comment: This is also very sensitive to locale.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for